# How to get 5.1 audio in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, speakers, surround-sound, stereo

I'm using Windows 7 and my speaker configuration is surround (5.1). I don't have any problem with games or my MP3 player. Games have surround output and it works perfect. MP3 player's output is stereo and my sound driver (creative) fills up the stereo to surround so it's perfect too. My only problem is with Chrome + YouTube + Html player. I can't hear the music from the rear speakers on Chrome.

I tried many things including `chrome.exe --disable-audio-output-resampler` switch for Chrome but nothing helped. Chrome's output is surround unlike my MP3 player. So the Creative sound driver can't fill it up to surround because it's already surround. YouTube videos don't have surround channels. They only have stereo channel. In this case, Chrome plays the video sound on first 2 channels. The other channels (3.1) are empty. Creative can't fill up the first 2 channels to 5.1 because it doesn't work on applications with surround output. It only works on stereo output.

So I've come up with an idea. If I can fool the Chrome to think that my speaker configuration is stereo (even if it's 5.1 physically), it would set it's output as stereo so my Creative driver could work on Chrome to fill its output to surround.

Does anybody know if I can fool a specific application (Chrome in this case) to believe I have stereo speaker configuration?

Comment: No idea guys ??

Comment: I have to bump this up :(

Comment: One last bump :(

Comment: Ok guys. Since Ujjwal's answer is a history now, I need a new solution to this problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the good old chrome flag is gone, the only way I can make this work is to add the parameter to chrome.exe shortcut.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --try-supported-channel-layouts

The downside of this, if Chrome is started by a different application (for example, clicking a web link in a chat application), it won't have upmixed audio. You have to quit Chrome and reopen it via the shortcut.

Answer (score 25):

**Update:** [As of Jan 13 - 2020] Now this option is *GONE* and the feature appears to be **active by default** (since version: 79.0.3945.117)
So **nothing** needs to be done. You can verify with a true 5.1 audio file played through the browser.
https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/multichannel.html

In order to **up-mix** stereo signal into a multichannel audio - you need to look into the options of your sound-card driver instead.

I use the old Creative X-Fi MB3 software to do that for me.

[**Previously** i.e. before Chrome 79]

<strike>Go to `chrome://flags` and enable `#try-supported-channel-layouts` flag; relaunch.</strike>

> chrome://flags/#try-supported-channel-layouts

This way it worked. Chrome::Youtube surround sound on my 5.1 speakers finally!

I could not get it working via the command line options. And perhaps the other command line options are now deprecated. 
Generally too, I recommend using the flags instead of the command line params

Comment: Looks like a better way. I have to test it first.

Comment: That worked! This is the new answer. Thank you!

Comment: Ok. This option is a history now. It's gone. I'm going to go crazy too.

Comment: Hello again Ujjwal. Regarding your Jan 13 - 2020 update:

Comment: Hello again Ujjwal. Regarding your Jan 13 - 2020 update:
My sound card has always been set to up-mix stereo signal into a multichannel audio. For example, I hear surround sound even when I'm playing stereo mp3 files using Winamp mp3 player. But that doesn't work for Chrome browser especially when playing stereo videos on YouTube. So, It doesn't look like the up-mix feature of Chrome is active by default.

Do you have any idea why YouTube videos aren't up-mixed even thou my sound card is set to up-mix correctly?

Comment: I just tested the stereo sound here without the try-supported-channel-layouts option: https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/stereo.html

They don't get up-mixed either.

It doesn't look like your Jan 13 - 2020 update is correct.

I'm 100% sure that my sound card is set to up-mix the stereo sources so Chrome's output is not stereo so it doesn't get up-mixed by the sound card.

Can you explain how you decided that the feature is active by default (since version: 79.0.3945.117)?

Answer (score 5):

Ive been looking for the same answer and finally found it so I thought I have to share it with you(and others with the same problem). 
The solution for me was to put " --force-wave-audio" at the end of the shortcut. I hope it helps others too!

Comment: OMG man. You got it. Now I can hear stereo music from all 4 speakers in youtube. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer (`try-supported-channel-layouts` flag) definitelly works for youtube videos, however, there appears to be an issue with similar symptoms on videos with stereo sound that prevents some videos from working on 5.1 setups on win 10 (9gag is full of those kinds of videos at the moment).  I figured a slightly off-topic answer might be appropriate here, because it is technically a 5.1 speaker issue and I landed on this question on when looking for a solution.

So what you can try is chrome **extensions**. There are multiple sound booster/3d (and similar) extensions available for chrome. The idea is to have chrome direct the audio to them and they play it on their own. I'm using [Aria-3D](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/3d-audio-within-your-web/mgielhihbmhidahbnhcelnbclheempel), because you can either keep on all the time or switch it off, and whenever you don't hear sound, click its icon, it remains off, but it takes control of the sound (as in unaltered sound plays through correct channels, or so I hope).

The downsides of these tools:

- Whenever a tab uses that extension you'll get a blue rectangle on the tab, indicating that "This tab's content is being shared" (according to devs that's because sound is being directed into extension).
- The ones I tried don't actually support 5.1 audio ( **they essentially convert to stereo** )